# GCP Compute Instance cannot be accessed

Tags: ubuntu, google-cloud-platform

I have a compute instance which hosts our database.

This has been working fine for the past few months.

suddenly now i cannot connect to the server via ssh (through gcp cloud shell) nor can i access the database which hosted on this instance, running ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might happen for various reasons like deleted firewall or change of IAM permissions or corruption of SSH keys. Have you checked the firewall rule?

You can use this [Toubleshooting document](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh-errors#ssh_troubleshooting_tool). This document explains **common errors**, **how to fix them**, and how to diagnose the failed SSH connections while connecting to the VM.

Here are some similar SO links [SO1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62952693), [SO2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35429727), in case if it is due to IAP proxy you can check this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XG2wJNBckns) to fix the firewall issue.